# How to wait until folder is created?

Tags: java, directory, google-colaboratory

I'm running java code on google colab which involves creating multiple folders and storing text files in those folders.

So I want to ensure that the folder is created successfuly before I can add the text file inside it and write to it.

Running my code in google colab is giving me errors related to creating folders which isn't
happening on my device, like sometimes the folder is created and sometimes not.

A simplification of my code would be:

```
while(!writtenToTextFile){
    //blocks that take a lot of time

    File folder=new File("folder");
    if(folder.mkdir()){
        //create the text file to store data
        writtenToTextFile=true;
    }
}
```

how can I wait until the folder is created for certain amount of time (e.g. 30 seconds) before the code runs into another round of the while loop to avoid executing the block that takes long time?

Comment: What are the errors? What do you see with `Files.createDirectory(folder.toPath())` (which will throw an exception telling you _what_ went wrong instead of just returning false)?

Answer (score 2):

> How to wait until folder is created?

When you use `java.io.File.mkdir()` or `.mkdirs()`, there is no need to wait.  These methods do not return before their work is complete, whether successful or not.  For example, [the API docs of `File.mkdir()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) say, in part:

> **Returns**:
> `true` if and only if the directory was created; `false` otherwise

This method may also throw an exception, but it does not return `true` without having successfully created the directory.

Note also that if that method returns `false`, that might simply mean that `File` corresponds to a directory that already exists, though there are other possibilities.

> Running my code in google colab is giving me errors related to creating folders which isn't happening on my device, like sometimes the folder is created and sometimes not.

Perhaps, then, you should ask a new question that focuses on specific code with which you can reproduce such an error, and the details of the environment in which you can do so.

> how can I wait until the folder is created for certain amount of time (e.g. 30 seconds) before the code runs into another round of the while loop to avoid executing the block that takes long time?

Supposing that colab provides a Java implementation whose standard library behaves as documented, you cannot wait for the directory to be created because it must already be created (or the attempt failed) before `File.mkdir()` returns.  You can add an arbitrary delay via `Thread.sleep()`, but it seems doubtful that that would resolve whatever problem it is that you are observing.